# Resize figures that are too high or too wide in LyX?

Tags: graphics, floats, lyx, dimensions

I would like to know how to define a preamble in Lyx to resize the width and the height if the figure is too wide or high.
I've already tried this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Determine if the image is too wide for the page.
\makeatletter
\def\ScaleIfNeeded{%
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Resize figures that are too wide for the page.
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]{#2}
}
```

However, the problem is that the images that are too high continue to be too high, how could I adjust in the preamble both width and height?

Comment: What is wrong with just making a right-click over the image and select the options to obtain  `\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=1 \textheight,keepaspectratio]{image}`?

Comment: Even simpler, why not right-click the image itself inside LyX and set the width/height using the GUI? I don't understand your problem, are you trying to apply these settings automatically whenever a huge graphic is inserted?

Answer (score 3):

You could add, to your LaTeX Preamble, the following:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
% Resize figures that are too wide for the page.
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[#1,max width=\linewidth,max height=\textheight]{#2}
}
```

[`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) allows to set the `maximum width` or `maximum height` of an included image and will modify it accordingly.

Note that if you set the `maximum height` to `\textheight`, an image included in a float *with* a caption might (will) not fit properly. You may have to consider something smaller than `\textheight`.

Comment: I don't know why but whit this LaTeX Preambule, when the image is too height I have the same problem, and it is out of the page, and with my original LyX document, it appears like an error. Like Juliohm said, I am trying to apply these settings automatically whenever a huge graphic is inserted because I have a lot of graphics, but now it seems impossible :-(

Comment: @user39674: What is the error?